# How to find what CLK driver is in use in Linux & also associated device vendor name

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I need  to find what `CLK` driver is in used in Linux. Is there any command that I can use to find which is currently running CLK driver in use. Also device vendor name associated with driver and a few words on the type of device associated with CLK driver like what they are and how they are different from system clock and Real Time Clock (RTC) in Linux

Comment: You can print a clock tree from which you may try to guess what the driver is in use for each clock (by its name).

Comment: System clock and RTC are completely orthogonal to the CCF (Common Clock Framework). Seems (based on your questions here on SO) you need some computer hardware 101 crash course.

Comment: @0andriy does btbcm makes sense. There is a module but it may be for usb.  There is bcm in clk inside /drivers in linux source

Comment: It’s unclear from your question what exact issue you are trying to solve. Your last comment only increased a confusion.